# How to transfrom log message using logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have below log messages like

2021-03-26 11:49:25.575: 2021-03-26 11:49:25.575 [INFO] 10.0.3.12 - "POST [https://api.kr-seo.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/a33da834-a7a7-48c2-9bf6-d3207849ad71/v1/workspaces/c6e3035b-411a-468d-adac-1ae608f7bf68/message?version=2018-07-10"](https://api.kr-seo.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/a33da834-a7a7-48c2-9bf6-d3207849ad71/v1/workspaces/c6e3035b-411a-468d-adac-1ae608f7bf68/message?version=2018-07-10%22) 200 462 ms

2021-03-26 11:49:26.514: 2021-03-26 11:49:26.514 [INFO] 10.0.3.12 + "POST [http://test-bff.lotteon.com/order/v1/mylotte/getOrderList"](http://test-bff.lotteon.com/order/v1/mylotte/getOrderList%22)

I want to transfrom using logstash like

```
"timestamp" : "2021-03-26 11:49:26.514",
"logLevel" : "INFO",
"IP" : "10.0.3.12",
"inout" : "-",
"Method" : "POST",
"url" : "https://api.kr-seo.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/a33da834-a7a7-48c2-9bf6-d3207849ad71/v1/workspaces/c6e3035b-411a-468d-adac-1ae608f7bf68/message?version=2018-07-10",
"status" : "200",
"duration" : "462 ms"
```

if, inout field is '+' that status/ duration filed are null ('')

How can I script logstash grok filter? (grok, mutate any other filter OK ...etc)
Help me..!

Answer (score 0):

```java
filter {

      grok { match => [ "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:predata} (?<inout>[-+]) \"%{GREEDYDATA:postdata}\""] }

      if [inout] == "+" 
        {
           grok { match => [ "message", "%{DATESTAMP:timestamp}: %{GREEDYDATA:data} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] %{IP:IP} (?<inout>[-+]) \"%{WORD:method} %{URI:url}\"" ] }
        }

      else {
          grok { match => [ "message", "%{DATESTAMP:timestamp}: %{GREEDYDATA:data} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] %{IP:IP} (?<inout>[-+]) \"%{WORD:method} %{URI:url}\" %{POSINT:statucode} %{POSINT:duration}" ] }
        }

   }
```

Now, you can remove the unnecessary fields:

```java
filter {
      mutate {
          remove_field => [
              "message",
              "predata",
              "postdata",
              "DATE_US",
              "IPV6",
              "USER",
              "USERNAME",
              "URIHOST",
              "IPORHOST",
              "HOSTNAME",
              "URIPATHPARAM",
              "port",
              "URIPATH",
              "URIPARAM"
          ]
          remove_tag => [
              "multiline",
              "_grokparsefailure"
          ]
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thx a lot :) but, 'inout' field I have below msg like
         "inout" => [
        [0] "+",
        [1] "+"
    ],

Comment: I want
"inout" => "+" or "inout" => "-"

Comment: I don't understand, I have answered it according to the logs shared by you. Please be more specific in question.

Comment: {
      "duration" => "22",
      "loglevel" => "INFO",
         "inout" => [
        [0] "-",
        [1] "-"
    ],
     "statucode" => "200",
    "@timestamp" => 2021-04-02T06:10:09.384Z,
            "IP" => "10.0.3.32",
        "method" => "POST",
       "message" => "2021-04-02 15:10:08.156: 2021-04-02 15:10:08.155 [INFO] 10.0.3.32 - \"POST http://test-bff.lotteon.com/member/v1/rest/memberBasicInfoInquiy\" 200 22 ms",
     "timestamp" => "21-04-02 15:10:08.156",
           "url" => "http://test-bff.lotteon.com/member/v1/rest/memberBasicInfoInquiy",
      "@version" => "1"
}

Comment: It comes out as above, but I wanna "inout" => "-"   or   "inout" => "+"  (only one)